# Magento 2.3 Constructor failed?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php-7.2

I have site run on hosting. but I get issue `vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/DateTime/Timezone.php(123): IntlDateFormatter->__construct('el_GR', 3, -1)`
Anybody have any idea help me check that?

Comment: When you getting this issue means on  which page?

Comment: on all page, @AmitBera